# Sound processing reference

Tags: audio

I am basically a .net programmer. I have a project in mind which is on core sound processing. But I want to do it in core language like assembly or c. I need some reference web sites or book names where I can found core format about sound or how to read sound file or from microphone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to learn about signal-processing, I would recommend you start with something a little easier to use than C or assembler.  That way, you can focus on the algorithms rather than all the hassle.

Comment: thanks. any book recommendation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work well with examples.  Here is some reference material also.  If you need anything else let me know.

1. [Audacity Open Source Audio program source code link](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/source)
2. I also recommend this - Closest thing between C++ and .NET [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP)
3. [Introduction to Audio Processing PDF](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~rocchess/htmls/corsi/SoundProcessing/SoundProcessingBook/sp.pdf)
4. [Book on Digital Signal Processing (An Electrical Engineering View)](http://books.google.com/books?id=3Cq7QgAACAAJ&dq=isbn:0133942899&cd=1)
5. [Book on Audio Signal Processing](http://books.google.com/books?id=IPMhDE-QWzQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0471972266&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false)
6. [Site on Introduction to Sound Processing](http://www.faqs.org/docs/sp/)